# Can I use Vue router to link to a div instead of a page?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, gridsome

I'm trying to create a route for an overlay. This overlay is toggled when pressing a button in my nav. Since its background is transparent/blur, it cannot be a separate site.

My goal is to make google register this path on my sitemap, therefore displaying it as a site link in its search results.

I am using Gridsome.